# How to fill the missing values of a feature based on the mean value of the feature relative to the target value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with some missing(NaN) values in the features. I want to impute them with the mean values corresponding to the target value that each row corresponds to.

`df_pk = pd.DataFrame({"f1": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], "f2": [2, np.nan,6, 8, 10, np.nan,14,16], "y": [1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1]})`

[image: Dataframe]

I need to impute the NaN values in place with the mean values corresponding to the target value y.

The new dataframe should look like this below.

[image: New dataframe]

I have tried using pandas groupby feature and the fillNa features but it isn't giving the expected results.
`df_pk['f2'].fillna(df.groupby('y')['f2'].transform('mean'))`

Comment: How is count `17` and `9` ?

Comment: How do you get 17 on second row and 9 on 8th row?

Comment: @kevinwu The mean of the values in the "f2" corresponding to target values 1 and 0

Comment: the means are 9 and 9.5, this doesn't match your provided output, also your code should be `df_pk['f2'].fillna(df_pk.groupby('y')['f2'].transform('mean'))` (`df_pk` not `df`)

Comment: And what are you going to do with NaNs in your *test* (or real-time, after deployment) data, where you will *not* have the targets?

Comment: @mozway Yes, The mean for target 1 will be (2+6+12+14)/4 = 8.5 and for target 2 will be (8+10)/2 = 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create dictionary to mapping your y value to f2's mean.

```
mean_dict = df.groupby(['y'])['f2'].mean().to_dict()
```

then fillna using map dictionary

```
df['f2'].fillna(df['y'].map(mean_dict))
```